# plot selected rows of numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, matplotlib

Consider a small numpy array:

```
array([[  0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.],
   [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
   [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  18.,  15.,  25.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
   [  0.,   0.,   0.,  23.,  19.,  20.,  20.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
   [  0.,   0.,  20.,  22.,  26.,  23.,  18.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
   [  0.,   0.,   0.,  23.,  16.,  20.,  13.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
   [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  18.,  20.,  18.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
   [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
   [  0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

I would like to plot, let say from the row number 3 to the row number 6, i.e. a section of my numpy array(I am coming from matlab backgroud). How could I loop this? or How could I plot multiple rows of my numpy array in the same graph?

So far I have tried; I define an arbitrary x:

```
x = np.arange(0,10)
```

then If I use

```
plt.plot(x,data[3,:])
```

to plot the third row and It does fine. The problem arises if I try:

```
plt.plot(x,data[3:4,:])
```

I get the error "x and y must have same first dimension", which I understand because he stacks row number 3 and row number 4 together, so that x and y do not have the same dimension. How can I overcome that?

Thank you

Comment: you would like to plot row number 3 to row number 6 with what? I mean, do you need to plot row3 vs row6 or row3-row6 vs something else?

Comment: from row number 3 to row number 6 vs an arbitrary x contaning the same number elements (10) in a row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error implies, your `data.shape = (1,10)` is inconsistent with your input `x.shape = (10,)`. To solve this problem you can just transpose your data using `.T`, *i.e.*

```
plt.plot(x, data[3:4,:].T)
```

Also, keep in mind that `data[3:4,:]` is the same as `data[3,:]`, you will need to use `data[3:5,:]` to get the 3rd and 4th rows, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
for i in range(3):
    plt.plot( x , data[ i , : ] )

plt.show()
```

If you want a range of rows ,for example from 3 to 6 , you can use:

`range(3,7,1)` , where 1 is the step , 3 is the starting row and 7 is the last row we want to plot (6 ) plus one

Comment: It is not really what I am looking for..It works for the first 3 rows but I want to plot from row number 3 to number 6, How can I do that with a similar loop?

Answer (score 2):

Just a better application of `psuedocubi's` answer.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,10,10)
y = np.array(YOUR DATA HERE)

plt.plot(x,a[3:4].T,'r--',label="x vs y1") #CONTAINS YOUR 3RD ROW
plt.plot(x,a[4:5].T,'g--',label="x vs y2") #CONTAINS YOUR 4TH ROW
plt.plot(x,a[5:6].T,'b--',label="x vs y3") #CONTAINS YOUR 5TH ROW
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

[image: YOUR DATA PLOTTED WITH ARBITARY X]

The `x` here as been plotted with your own data!